# PHP - Trouble with SQL query

Tags: php, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemcategory= 123 AND itemname LIKE '%abc%';
```

I want to pass parameters to `itemcategory` and `itemname`; I tried something like this:

```
SELECT *  FROM items WHERE itemcategory=".'$categoryid'." AND itemname LIKE" ."'%$itemname%'"." AND shopid=5003;
```

It didn't work. Can anyone help?

Comment: This is not regex.

Comment: In what way did it not work? Did you get a specific error message?

Comment: Syntax error I believe.

Comment: the 2nd sql statement has the quotes mixed up ~ more like `"SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemcategory='".$categoryid."' AND itemname LIKE '%".$itemname."%' AND shopid=5003;";`

Comment: Yeah syntax error at like 45

Comment: @AlexParser go back and run it again and post the exact error message that you receive.

Comment: $itemname is the parameter and I want to pass it in the place of abc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-insert-statement)

Comment: What is the actual resulting query being executed and what is the actual error message?  "I'm building a query and getting an error" doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\inetpub\vhosts\personalwebars.com\httpdocs\compare.php on line 163

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is nearly right, but you can de complicate the string concatenation, if you remember that `$var` is automatically expanded in a double quoted string

So this is easier to read and notice spacing issues, which is all I think that was wrong with your statement

```
$q =   "SELECT * 
        FROM items 
        WHERE itemcategory = '$categoryid' 
          AND itemname LIKE '%$itemname%'
          AND shopid=5003";
```

Assuming you have valid data in these variables this should work

> The only danger with doing this rather than using prepared parameterised queries is that you risk [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
>   Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
>   [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
>   Use [prepared statement and parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)